# How to use Dataframes in pyspark machine learning?

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning, pyspark

I've learned briefly how to use RDDs to build ML models but in the past i've typically built my ML models using dataframes. I know spark.ml is the DataFrame API for spark machine learning but I haven't been able to find examples on how to utilize it.

My question is can you provide an example of how Dataframes can be used to build a spark machine learning model?

P.S. Sorry if this question is not appropriate, wasn't sure where to post this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick example I quickly whipped up just now.

```
import pyspark.ml                as ml
import pyspark.ml.feature        as ft
import pyspark.ml.classification as cl

data = sc.parallelize([
     (1, 'two',  3.4, 0)
    ,(2, 'four', 9.1, 1)
    ,(3, 'one',  2.1, 0)
    ,(4, 'five', 2.6, 0)
]).toDF(['id', 'counter', 'continuous', 'result'])

si  = ft.StringIndexer(inputCol='counter', outputCol='counter_idx')
ohe = ft.OneHotEncoder(inputCol=si.getOutputCol(), outputCol='counter_enc')
va  = ft.VectorAssembler(inputCols=['counter_enc', 'continuous'], outputCol='features')

lr  = cl.LogisticRegression(maxIter=5, featuresCol='features', labelCol='result')

pip = ml.Pipeline(stages=[si, ohe, va, lr])
pip.fit(data).transform(data).select(data.columns+['probability', 'prediction']).show()
```

You can also check the notebooks to Denny's and my book: https://github.com/drabastomek/learningPySpark/blob/master/Chapter06/LearningPySpark_Chapter06.ipynb

Hope this helps.